# dynamic Datatable column width based on content length

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable , i want that the column width be dynamic based on the content length , i made a function that calculate the content length (`call()`) but the problem is the content returns an empty string :

```
<p:column sortBy="action" rendered="#{configuration.conf2.action}" width="#{cdrMmscRecBean.call(c.action)}"  >
    <f:facet name="header" > 
    <h:outputText value="Action"  />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{c.action}" />
</p:column>
```

c.action returns an empty string .

Comment: What is the c.action code?

Answer (score 4):

Very often it is enough to setup style for data table like

```
<p:dataTable tableStyle="width: auto;">
```

Then you don't need to calculate column width in special method, but table will adjust width of columns based on content. At least it works for simple cases.